# Creating a table with variables in the cells and a variable number of rows

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli, html-table

I'm making a webpage to display the information in a database. One section has a table that should list the application being used (name, the type of media the application is, the content that is streamed through the application, and the user's rating for the application). So, four columns per row. I want to display all of the applications a user uses (so, multiple rows) and while I have something that works for displaying a single application, I would really appreciate some help on how to make it so that multiple rows are generated depending on the number of applications the user is using and so that the cells in the row will display the correct information. Here's what I have so far:

```
        <tbody class="header">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><a href="#demo12">Applications</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id="demo12">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Media Type</td>
        <td>Streamed Content</td>
        <td>Rating Given</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php
            while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
            echo $user["aName"];
            endwhile; 
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php
            while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
            echo $user["aMType"];
            endwhile; 
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php
            while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
            echo $user["aStreamed"];
            endwhile; 
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php
            while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
            echo $user["aRating"];
            endwhile; 
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: No experience with php, but looking at your code should the loop be around the tr element? I am assuming you want rows repeated, not elements in each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put while loop outside your `tr` tag

```
<?php
    while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
?>
<tr>
   <td>
       <?php 
           echo $user["aName"];
       ?>
   </td>
   <td>
       <?php 
           echo $user["aMType"];
       ?>
   </td>
   ...
   ...
</tr>
<?php
   endwhile;
?>
```